# Postgres - CREATE TABLE FROM SELECT

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables, one contains a large list of IDs and Info regarding those ids.

I have a second table `Graph` which just has two columns, each column contains the aforementioned id numbers, multiple times. I want to `trim` the size of my `Info` table by selecting only those ids that appear in my graph and creating a new smaller Info table. Is there a simple way of doing this?

```
CREATE TABLE FROM SELECT?
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 66):

It's as easy as:

```
create table new_table
as 
select t1.col1, t2.col2
from some_table t1
   join t2 on t1.id = t2.some_id;
```

You can use any select statement for that. The column names of the new table are defined by the column aliases used in th query.

More details in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtableas.html

Comment: Thank you! ID numbers in t1.col1 and t2.col can repeat multiple times, will this affect table 1? I don't want duplicated Ids. The ID field is labeled as PRIMARY SERIAL. Thanks!

Comment: @user2923767 If you don't want duplicates you need to apply a `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` - just as you would with any regular query.

Answer (score 19):

You can create TEMP table if you need those small table only for that session. you can use below query to do that.

```
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_table;
    CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_table AS
     SELECT 
       i.id as info_id, i.information as information
     FROM
      info i
      INNER JOIN graph g ON i.id = g.id;
```

Now you can use this temp_table for your next table in the function.

```
                    OR
```

you can also create table like below (if you not want to create it as TEMP):

```
CREATE TABLE temp_table AS
     SELECT 
       i.id as info_id, i.information as information
     FROM
      info i
      INNER JOIN graph g ON i.id = g.id;
```