# How to create a new table from 2 existing tables, using conditions and SUM?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a new table, based on data contained in 2 other tables. I will write the logic here;

t1.c1 -> t3.c1

t1.c2 -> t3.c2

t2.c1 -> t3.c3

t1.c1 is a unique identifier (registration number), there are duplicates of this in all tables, but I need the new table (t3) to only hold one of each.

t1.c2 is a net value, there are many of these values associated with a single unique identifier, and I am trying to SUM all of these, to their respective unique identifier within the new table (t3).

t2.c1 is a distance, there are many of these values associated with a single unique identifier, again I am trying to SUM all of these in the new table in one row next to their unique identifier (t3).

Ultimately this new table (t3) will have 3 columns; c1 will be unique, c2 and c3 should be the SUM taken from their original tables.

I have tried joining the 2 tables together, and creating a new one from these. However I become stuck at the part where I am using a unique column, and 2 sum columns.

```
INSERT INTO table3(column1) 
SELECT DISTINCT "column1" FROM table1

UPDATE table3
SET column2 = CASE
WHEN column1 = column1 FROM table1 
THEN SUM(column2) FROM table1
END;
```

My Code is currently split into 2 seconds, the first part currently works, but the second part is not working (but hopefully shows you the logic behind what I am trying to achieve!)

The results are; this simply does not work. I understand the logic of how this should be done, and I am sure there is a way to achieve this - but I have no idea and cannot find any information on this problem.

Comment: Here it would be really helpful to see some sample data and the expected output. There are many things which are not quite clear.

Comment: Furthermore: Your use case seems not to be a good idea. Aggregating data from other tables hardly into a third one. What if data changes in table 1? Wouldn't it be necessary to change it in t3 as well? It looks like a job for a view instead

Comment: This issue appears to be answered here: [Postgres - CREATE TABLE FROM SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22953450/postgres-create-table-from-select).