# create table from select - any options to refresh or auto update?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22953450/postgres-create-table-from-select) while searching for ways to create a table based on already existing tables in SQL (Postgres).

The accepted answer looks appealing due to it's simplicity. To create a new table based on a select query just:

```
create table new_table
as 
select t1.col1, t2.col2
from some_table t1
   join t2 on t1.id = t2.some_id;
```

My question is, what options to I have, if any, for creating a new, up to date new_table? So, if and when some_table or t2 update, so does new_table?

I read about materialized views and refreshes [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/sql-refreshmaterializedview.html). That sounds close to what I want... is that the 'conventional' approach? Can one schedule these refreshes, e.g. every morning at 8am? if yes what is the name of the utility that I want to search for?

This is an analytics database not an application database. If I was somehow able to update tables or views once a day, that would work fine for our needs.

I've used Hive in the past and had to create pipelines with various tools. What is the equivalent approach with RDBMS?

A view would be ideal except this query takes about ~10 minutes to run each time. I've tried adding some index' but find it challenging to get a hard 'add' / 'don't add' decision on where to place them. I tried adding a few with no noticable change in performance for this particular query.

Here's the explain result if it offers any pointers:

```
CTE Scan on combined  (cost=14385084156.03..14835854011.07 rows=22538492752 width=232)
  CTE sessions
    ->  Seq Scan on sessions  (cost=0.00..1664687.64 rows=20871777 width=148)
          Filter: (date >= ((CURRENT_DATE - 1) - 30))
  CTE ecom_events
    ->  Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=216899.81..289934.85 rows=215971 width=70)
          Group Key: events.dimension1, events.event_action, events.event_label, events.dimension5
          ->  Gather Merge  (cost=216899.81..282375.86 rows=431942 width=70)
                Workers Planned: 2
                ->  Partial GroupAggregate  (cost=215899.79..231519.01 rows=215971 width=70)
                      Group Key: events.dimension1, events.event_action, events.event_label, events.dimension5
                      ->  Sort  (cost=215899.79..218143.04 rows=897301 width=66)
                            Sort Key: events.dimension1, events.event_action, events.event_label, events.dimension5
                            ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events  (cost=0.00..84062.51 rows=897301 width=66)
                                  Filter: ((event_category)::text = 'ecom'::text)
  CTE combined
    ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=13425243591.58..14383129533.54 rows=22538492752 width=232)
          Group Key: s.date, s.user_type, s.device_category, s.operating_system, s.channel_grouping, (COALESCE(e.event_action, 'All Sessions'::character varying)), (COALESCE(e.event_label, 'All Sessions'::character varying))
          ->  Sort  (cost=13425243591.58..13481589823.46 rows=22538492752 width=244)
                Sort Key: s.date, s.user_type, s.device_category, s.operating_system, s.channel_grouping, (COALESCE(e.event_action, 'All Sessions'::character varying)), (COALESCE(e.event_label, 'All Sessions'::character varying))
                ->  Merge Right Join  (cost=6745457.92..344876108.50 rows=22538492752 width=244)
                      Merge Cond: ((e.session_id)::text = (s.session_id)::text)
                      ->  Sort  (cost=29941.17..30481.09 rows=215971 width=96)
                            Sort Key: e.session_id
                            ->  CTE Scan on ecom_events e  (cost=0.00..4319.42 rows=215971 width=96)
                      ->  Materialize  (cost=6715516.76..6819875.64 rows=20871777 width=212)
                            ->  Sort  (cost=6715516.76..6767696.20 rows=20871777 width=212)
                                  Sort Key: s.session_id
                                  ->  CTE Scan on sessions s  (cost=0.00..417435.54 rows=20871777 width=212)
```

Query in question:

```
/* 
Ecommere funnel with various filters. Grouped at event and date level + any filters included 
*/


with 


/* session scoped data */
sessions as (
select 
    dimension1 as session_id,
    dimension2 as client_id,
    date,
    user_type,
    device_category,
    operating_system,
    country,
    region,
    source,
    medium,
    campaign,
    channel_grouping,
    sessions,
    bounces,
    transactions,
    transaction_revenue
from ga_flagship_ecom.sessions

-- 30 days at a time, otherwise breach data studio 100K rows limit
where date >= (current_date - 1) - 30
),


/* events with category ecom  */
ecom_events as(
select 
    dimension1 as session_id,
    event_action,
    event_label,
    dimension5 as plan,

    -- just looking to reduce with group by, dosn't matter which metric
    sum(unique_events) as unique_events
from ga_flagship_ecom.events 
where event_category = 'ecom'
group by 1,2,3,4
),

combined as (
select 
    s.date,
    s.user_type,
    s.device_category,
    s.operating_system,
    s.country,
    s.region,
    s.source,
    s.medium,
    s.campaign,
    s.channel_grouping,
    coalesce(e.event_action, 'All Sessions') as event_action,
    coalesce(e.event_label, 'All Sessions') as event_label,
    count(distinct s.client_id) as users,
    sum(s.sessions) as sessions,
    sum(s.bounces) as bounces,
    sum(s.transactions) as transactions,
    sum(s.transaction_revenue) as revenue
from sessions s 
left join ecom_events e on e.session_id = s.session_id
group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
)


select *
from combined;
```

Comment: It sounds like you want a plain old standard view.  Why not use a view?  It the data set is extremely large then perhaps a materialized view is in order.  In all likelyhood it would need to be in the 10s of millions of records range for a mat view to be in order.

Comment: In this case, because my query takes so long to run, ~10 minutes. That's fine for me but since thse data will feed into a dashboard with filter drop downs, I need something faster for the end users.

Comment: Before you go down the mat view path, review the explain plan and see if you can create some index(es) to avoid full table scans.  Performance tuning can go a long way..

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I was reading through https://use-the-index-luke.com/ and did add some index's. But I've not yet seen a noticeable improvement in this particular case. 

Re your comment on materialized view. The results are maybe ~2M but the tables being used to generate the result each contain tens of millions of records. Does that seem like materialized view territory?

Comment: Just try a materialized view. In terms of performance, this will be very close to your current approach. Use a simple script with `cron` for automatic refreshing the view.

Comment: @klin OK thank you, I will try that.

Comment: Should I delete? Appreciate my question may be too broad

Comment: @DougFir a materialized view would work and it will be slow only when the view is refreshed but it will be fast when it is being selected by the end user. It will definitely help. I saw the execution plan, it seems most of the slowness is around sorting as it has several millions in cost - s.date, s.user_type, s.device_category, s.operating_system, s.channel_grouping, (COALESCE(e.event_action, 'All Sessions'::character varying)), (COALESCE(e.event_label, 'All Sessions'::character varying)). I think the COALESCE statements are causing issue, try removing them and see if refresh time reduces.

Comment: Thanks for the tips @Salim! Noted about coalesce. About 'slowness is around sorting'. Could you expand on that? There's no `order by' statement... I'd 'feel' good if I knew there was nothing particularly unreasonable about my query and that it's simply a matter of having  alarge set of data. I will also try out the materialized view.

Comment: @klin as a follow up. If I'm going to make a materialized view with cron job refresh, would I be as well to create a table with cron update with new data each morning? That way I could add index'. I.e. Why materialized view over a table?

Comment: @DougFir - A materialized view in fact is a table. You **can** create indexes on a materialized view. When it comes to differences, a materialized view stores the query used to initialize it. And maybe most significant, you can [refresh a view concurrently.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-refreshmaterializedview.html) If the last is not important for you, I would say the choice between these options is a matter of style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dynamic view is better as data will always be fresh and there won't be any extra space used. If tuning can't be done then materialized view should be used.

Here are query tuning tips that can be useful in your case. This will help for  materialized view or a dynamic view whichever way you want to go.

1. Avoid joining with an inline view having 'group by' init because it prevents predicate push down. Instead of joining with 'ecom_events' which has group by in it, join with 'ga_flagship_ecom.events' table directly and then group by on the result.
2. ga_flagship_ecom.sessions can be range partitioned on "date" column. When you are needing data for last 30 days then one or few partitions will be scanned instead of full table.
3. Build the final view without any 'group by' in it. Apply the group by condition while queuing the view.
4. Index both tables on session_id as join is happening on this.

```
    combined as (
    select 
        s.date,
        s.user_type,
        s.device_category,
        s.operating_system,
        s.country,
        s.region,
        s.source,
        s.medium,
        s.campaign,
        s.channel_grouping,
        coalesce(e.event_action, 'All Sessions') as event_action,
        coalesce(e.event_label, 'All Sessions') as event_label,
        count(distinct s.client_id) as users,
        sum(s.sessions) as sessions,
        sum(s.bounces) as bounces,
        sum(s.transactions) as transactions,
        sum(s.transaction_revenue) as revenue
    from sessions s 
    left join ga_flagship_ecom.events e on e.session_id = s.session_id
    where e.event_category = 'ecom'
    )
```

Apply group by condition and predicates while querying combined. This will push session_id predicate inside the query, few results will be returned and the group by will be faster too.

```
    select ... from combined c where c.session_id = ? group by ....
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding appropriate index(es) here rather than the hassle of maintaining and refreshing a materialised view. If you have enough CPU available, you can also increase the no of workers available for the scan.